# Do I have to create a reference for each text I have in a panel, if I want to access them to modify?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a panel with 8 text field, 4 are used as descriptive field (what a label would do, basically), while the other 4 are modified with values.

I am creating a GameObject variable for every element that I have in the panel, using find to find the specific text element. I can leverage on the fact that each text object has only one text object attached to it, so I can address to it directly with GetComponent

```
panel_info = GameObject.Find("infopanel");

textfield1 = GameObject.Find("text_name");
textfield2 = GameObject.Find("text_age");
textfield3 = GameObject.Find("text_role");
textfield4 = GameObject.Find("text_field");

textfield1.GetComponent<Text>().text = "joe";
textfield2.GetComponent<Text>().text = "22";
textfield3.GetComponent<Text>().text = "striker";
textfield4.GetComponent<Text>().text = "attack";
```

While this works, I can't foresee myself creating 20-30 objects if a panel has more info to display.
Since I have the reference to the object Panel, is there a way to address directly the text field which is a child of the panel, using the text field name for example?

So if a panel has 4 text field, I can modify each of it addressing directly by name, and then using `GetComponent<Text>().text`to change the value.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly correct.  if you have 100 `Text`, you will need 100 variables, one for each one.  How else could it possibly be?  This is why making games takes a *long* time and pays *incredibly* well.  What did you think would happen?   There's no "AI system" to do the work for you. you know?

Comment: In other languages, I can access the textfield on a form, without the need to create a variable for that; which is why I was looking for an alternative to create N variables. A textfield has a name; if I know the parent, I can access the child and then the text property of that object; while in Unity; I find hard to do so, because the gameobject does not know about the children; nor I can call a child by name (from what I can tell), unless I allocate a variable. I don't expect something doing everything for me; that's a given...been writing windows apps for more than a decade, not in unity :)

Comment: *"nor I can call a child by name (from what I can tell), unless I allocate a variable"* Yes, it is very true that in ECS it is extremely confusing that you don't "just have fucking variables for things 'in the class'!!" In OO programming if something is "under" a Class (I mean .. its' a member of the class, a variable) then of course, self-evidently, obviously it's a variable and you can access it.   But in ECS (which is unconnected in any way to OO - not to say we're not using an OO language here *for* an ECS system) there is ***no particular relationship*** between a parent-child GameObject

Comment: ... don't forget: the parent-child ***GameObject relationship*** means nothing whatsoever more than that ***the GPU applies the multiple of the `Transform` 4d matrix to the 'child' item*** ... that is ALL it means.  (ie, "when you move the parent, the child happens to move").  The fact that in the "heirarchy panel" they are shown "one under the other" is very suggestive of some sort of ***Class-like, OO-like, 'heirarchical' relationship, but it is just totally and utterly unconnected in anyway - at all - there is utterly zero relationship of that nature***.

Comment: indeed note that if you have a game object "Tank" and you happen to have "below" it (ie, transform.parent = transform) some other items (say, a few "Soldier" and a "Turret" and 16 "Wheel").  Then, ***in terms of Classes*** there is just utterly no relationship, whatsoever.  Note that you could ***replace*** one of those items, say, Soldier, with something just utterly unconnected to Tank in anyway!  (like .. your sound effects!  or "a cloud"!  or literally anything).  of course!, in OO, and Classes, you can't just meaninglessly put "sound effects!" under "tank!" .. right?!

Comment: To repeat: that what you see in the "hierarchy" in the Unity editor ***confusingly, makes us think of OO programming, but there is just utterly no relationship whatsoever to Class or Class structure***.  The heirarchy is ***nothing more than*** an indicator of how one particular system in unity -- not PhysX, not Mecanim, in fact the Transform matrices -- are connected. Note that sometimes people say -- for example -- that panel should show the *Mecanim hierarchy*, NOT the transform matrix hierarchy. Mybe, but again it would have ***absolutely no connection*** to the hierarchy one naturally ...

Comment: ...naturally thinks of in OO !!  So that's the deal!  :)    if you happen to want to have variables, that happen to connect to, something that just happens to be "under that thing, in the Unity-editor-shown hierarchy", then just do that.  Recall too that that class (say Tank), ***may not even BE ON*** such a game object!!  It's just that you happened to drag a "Tank" script to some particular game object!!!

Comment: You could, as it happens, instantiate a Tank *class* (ie: x  - new Tank() ) and that just has ***nothing, whatsoever, to do with game objects ........ it's not even ON a game object!!!***.  Conversely you could if you happen to want to, drag the Tank script on to a game object that is a soldier, rock, cloud, the unity camera, or whatever.  It's just a script you drag on to things.  Hopefully, this makes clear the "surprise" everyone feels  in Unity who comes from normal OO that "why the hell is there no variables to the objects 'under' me here?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **MUST NOT** call `GetComponent<Text>()` each time you want to access/modify text.

This is an ***extremely basic fact*** about Unity.

It is ***immediately mentioned*** in the relevant manual entries.

Since you have **8** textbox and I don't know how long you update each one. It would be good if you **cache**  all of them in the **beginning** of the game then use them **later** on **without** `GetComponent<Text>()`. This will **improve** performance a lot and make your frame-rate happy.

Array looks good for something like this. And you need to comment each one too.

```
public Text[] textBoxArray;
```

On the editor, Expand the "**Text Box Array**" and change the array **Size** to **8**.
Now **drag** each **GameObject** with the **text** to the arrays in **order**. If you do it in **order**, you can easily remember their names and be able to access them in order.

For example, if the first text gameobecjt you dragged to the array is called `text_name`, the access it, you use `textBoxArray[0]`. The second text which is `text_age` can be accessed with `textBoxArray[1]`. .....

To make it easier for you later on, you should have multiple line comment that describes which array points to what.You do this so that when you return to modify your code months after, you won't have to look around in the Editor to find what points to what. For example:

```
/*
textBoxArray[0] = text_name
textBoxArray[1] = text_age
textBoxArray[2] = text_role
textBoxArray[3] = text_field
*/
```

No performance lost and that decreases the amount of code in your game.

**Initializing the arrays by code instead of the Editor**

Assuming you want to initialize the arrays by code instead of the Editor. You can do it in the start function like below.

```
public Text[] textBoxArray;
  void Start()
    {
     //Create arrays of 8
     textBoxArray = new Text[8]; //8 texts

     //Cache all the Text GameObjects
     textBoxArray[0] = GameObject.Find("/infopanel/text_name").GetComponent<Text>();
     textBoxArray[1] = GameObject.Find("/infopanel/text_age").GetComponent<Text>();
     textBoxArray[2] = GameObject.Find("/infopanel/text_role").GetComponent<Text>();
     textBoxArray[3] = GameObject.Find("/infopanel/text_field").GetComponent<Text>();
    }
```

You should notice that `GameObject.Find()` starts with "/" and that increases performance too as it will only search for Texts under "**infopanel**" instead of searching in the **whole** scene.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of slightly improving your *fantastic* answer.  Of course, you should feel free to rollback, keep, or change further.  A terrific and generous canonical answer for new hobbyists trying Unity.

Comment: I take them all as beginners and that's why I try to explain it thoroughly. Thanks for the editing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do cache all my componets when I call awake; which is why I was asking if there is a way to not allocate from the start, a variable, that hold the reference to the specific text object. Also I didn't mention that I want to do everything from code; I do not have one single screen, so going with the editor adding each element by hand, would go against myself, in case I have to change something (let's move 300 fields! :) ). At this point a dictionary would fit better, since I can use the field name as key for each text field , and I believe the dictionary is fast.

Comment: I get your point thou, caching is much faster than search for the value every single time; performance wise is better to create N variables, than calling X times the find method. All of you are giving me very good info about how to approach the solution; I didn't consider performance optimization at this phase (the game barely moves on its own, out of prototype phase), but considering how many times I change such values, I have to fact that in too. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I know you didn't mention that you want to do everything from code but I provided that for others who may need to do that later on. What I did was provide something I've done before and something that would make your game run with more FPS. I have used dictionary before and the performance gap of Dictionary and Array is unbelievable. What Array did in 367 ms, Dictionary did it in 2419 ms. According to you, don't care about performance right now and would prefer re-writing your work from scratch later on. You can use whatever method works for you. Happy programming!

Comment: Also there is a reason you should avoid doing EVERYTHING from the Editor. For example, when you have hundreds or even thousands of GAMEOBJECTS but then your project breaks/crashes for some reasons such as Upgrading Unity. Recreating the scene by dragging and dropping objects to Script would take forever because you have to put all gameobjects in the right slot or your game wont work properly. but if you have stuff like this "GameObject.Find("/infopanel/text_name")". You can easily recreate that by Creating a GameObject called "infopanel" then creating a child of it called "text_name"....

Comment: I am Ok with the Editor doing some of the work , like I should not write every time the code to push a button; but for other things I like to keep control over the code, even if this goes against the simplicity in Unity. After all, Unity was made to allow anyone to make games; which is a good thing on one side, while it is not so good from another perspective. I find already hard to debug now, since there is this "decoupling" between the object itself and the container, but if I would do everything from the editor, and debug; I would rather stab my leg with a screwdriver :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your hierarchy is setup that all your TextMeshes are children of the panel, you could use the [Transform.Find](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html) method to get each child, then it's TextMesh, and assign a value.

So, for example, if you wanted to assign the value "Joe" to the TextMesh attached to "text_name", which in turn is a child of "infopanel", you could do the following

```
panel_info = GameObject.Find("infopanel");
panel_info.transform.Find("text_name").GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = "Joe";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The find method is equivalent to the gameobject.find and getchildcomponent; but I see that you can pass a name as parameter, which would work for what I need. Thanks.